# minimizing the connection cost of a rest web service

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, iis-7

I am connecting to an IIS 7 rest web server and sending up gps readings. We save the reading every 20 seconds but submit it to the web service every 60 seconds.

Here is my connection:

```
    var readings = Reading.GetUnProcessReadings().ToList();

    var gpsreadings = new List<TruckGpsReading>();

    history.History = "TruckGpsReading count: " + readings.Count();

    var count = 1;
    while (readings.Any())
    {
      {
        gpsreadings = new List<TruckGpsReading>();
        if (readings.Any())
        {
          history.History = "No. Transactions to process: " + count;
          foreach (var reading in readings)
          {
            history.History = "Currently reading #" + count;
            history.History = "Processing reading: " + reading.DateTimeOfReading;
            Logging.Log("Starting ProcessGpsFile.ProcessReading 3", "ProcessReading", Apps.RemoteTruckService);
            var gpsreading = new TruckGpsReading();
            gpsreading.DateTimeOfReading = reading.DateTimeOfReading;
            gpsreading.Direction = reading.Direction;
            gpsreading.DriverNumber = CurrentIniSettings.DriverNumber;
            gpsreading.GpsReadingId = reading.ReadingId;
            gpsreading.Latitude = (float) reading.Latitude;
            gpsreading.Longitude = (float) reading.Longitude;
            gpsreading.Speed = reading.Speed;                
            gpsreading.TruckNumber = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CurrentIniSettings.TruckNumber) ? "99" : CurrentIniSettings.TruckNumber;
            gpsreadings.Add(gpsreading);
            TotalReadings++;
            count++;
          }

          var response = client.SaveGpsReadings(globalSetting.TokenId, globalSetting.SourceId, gpsreadings.ToArray());
          if (response != "true")
          {
            history.History = "Transactions NOT saved: " + response;
            Logging.Log("ProcessGpsFile.ProcessReading: " + response, "ProcessReading", Apps.RemoteTruckService);
          }
          else
          {
            history.History = "Transactions saved.";
            Logging.Log("ProcessGpsFile.ProcessReading: Reading.DeleteGpsReadings(readings)", "ProcessReading",
                        Apps.RemoteTruckService);
            Reading.DeleteGpsReadings(readings);
          }
        }
```

And this is the TruckGpsReading:

```
  [DataContract]
  public class TruckGpsReading
  {
    [DataMember]
    public string DriverNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string TruckNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public float Latitude { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public float Longitude { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DateTimeOfReading { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Speed { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Direction { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int OdometerReading { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid GpsReadingId { get; set; } 

  }
```

I am finding that the amount of information being sent approx 256 bytes for each record but it seems the connection is in the 30k area. I'm not sure what causes this or if there is a better way around this.

My problem is when the data is sent up, it is going over a cell network. These networks are limited on the monthly data usage and I'm trying to minimize that usage.

If I were to connect the the service when my application opens and stay connected, is this a bad idea? I was thinking we could connect when the application starts and have the 1 time connection cost instead of connecting every time we go to send. **EDIT** I Wanted to add that this program will run on a daily basis for about 8 to 10 hours.

Also, is there a way to cut down on the connection costs or to find out what is doing when connected?

I know this is a lot of questions but I'm new to web services.

Comment: are you tsting on a real device ? if that is the case are you sure that no other program is also sending data at the same time ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia I am connecting from a pc. I am using a program called [NetBalancer](http://seriousbit.com/) which will tell me how much data is being sent per program. I reset it's totals after after each send to verify the information. When it firsts connects it jumps to about 30k and then I reset it. A min later it jumps up ~512 bytes, and then another min ~512 bytes, etc. This is the only program connecting to this service.